# reduce using cl-loop facility

Tags: emacs, elisp

[CL library manual "map over sequences"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Mapping-over-Sequences.html#Mapping-over-Sequences) says "All of these mapping operations can be expressed conveniently in terms of the cl-loop macro" but I don't see how cl-reduce can be expressed in terms of cl-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how "conveniently" expressed it is, but here's my take on it:

```
(defun loop-reduce (func sequence &rest initial-element)
  (loop with result =
        (or (car initial-element)
            (prog1 (car sequence)
              (setf sequence (cdr sequence))))
        for x in sequence do (setf result (funcall func result x))
        finally (return result)))

(loop-reduce '+ '(1 2 3 4 5))
;; 15

(loop-reduce '+ '(1 2 3 4 5) 10)
;; 25
```